# Where's the default Farsi(Persian) font file?

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-font-family

There is a default font for each language in ubuntu, which is displayed in menus, captions, etc. As far as I'm concerned they're located in /usr/shared/fonts.
My problem is that I can't find the default Farsi font file, no matter wherever and how long I search! Where is that ttf file?
P.S.: I've looked into the ubuntu family folder; nothing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "French font", "German font" and "English font"—those languages all use the Latin script system.  The same is true for Farsi (`fa`); there is no single "Farsi font" file, but the Arabic (script) character set is used by several languages and a single font can cover all of these.

If you have your own `.ttf` font that you are used to reading and would prefer to use, you can set it as default with:

1. Go to the Ubuntu Software Centre
2. Search for and install "Advanced Settings" (aka "GNOME Tweak Tool")
3. Double-click your preferred `.ttf` to open in GNOME Font Viewer
4. Click [Install]
5. Use the Advanced Settings tool to select the name of the font you just installed.

*(The changes are installed in your own user area, and do not require administrator permissions).*